# надо найти минимум из введенных чисел

Tags: python

```
X = min
n = int(input("Введите количество учеников"))
for i in range(n):
   Xi = int(input("Введите рост ученика"))
if X < min:
        print(X)
```

Выходит такая ошибка:

```
5:0] '<' not supported between instances of '<native JS>' and '<native JS>'
```

Comment: Этот код не может выдать такую ошибку, зато выдаст другие. Выполняй код в нормальном интерпретаторе питона, а не непонятно где.

Comment: @Эникейщик Может он его на js запускает? ;D

Comment: у нас это задание выполняется только в этом интерпретаторе

Comment: Замени min на что-нибудь другое и никогда не используй встроенные функции языка в качестве имени переменной.

Answer (score 2):

Не знаю чего вообще вы хотели сказать вашим кодом, вот как я бы написал (по расплывчатому условию):

```
print(min(map(int, input().split(' '))))
```

Comment: данные вводится не в одной строке а в нескольких

Comment: @Danis Чего там хотел сказать автор непонятно. Пусть чуток подумает сам, раз не может дать другим ;D

Comment: а зачем вопрос сделал общим?

Comment: @Danis Потому что это толком не ответ. Так что <s>те минусы что я за него получу</s> я не имею права получать за него репу. ;D

Answer (score 0):

Вы не правильно используете min(). Оно находит минимум из заданных чисел.
В Вашем случае я бы использовал вариант предыдущего программиста, но т.к. по коду видно что человек - новичок, предложу свой код.

```
n = int(input("Введите количество учеников:\n"))
minn = 0
for i in range(n):
    x = int(input("Введите рост ученика:\n"))
    if minn > x:
        minn = x
print(x)
```

или

```
n = int(input("Введите количество учеников:\n"))
m = []
for i in range(n):
    m.append(int(input("Введите рост ученика:\n")))
print(min(m))
```